# A Normal distribution variable in the power of N

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, moments, transform

If $X$ is normal distributed random variable, what is the distribution of $|X|^n$?

I am struggling to understand the distribution.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If the underlying normal distribution has mean $0$ then I suspect you have a particular [generalised gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution)

Comment: what properties do you need to know about? n=2 is easy (chi-2(1)), but I think it could be very hard to derive much information for general n ...

Comment: Thanks! X is normal distributed, Xn= |X^n|. the question I am really trying to solve is "is Xn a fat tail distribution"

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y=|X|^n$

Then for $y>0$ you have a CDF of $$F_n(Y)=\mathbb P(Y \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le \sqrt[n]{y}) - \mathbb P(X \le -\sqrt[n]{y})\\=\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{y}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-\sqrt[n]{y}-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \\=\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{y}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{y}+\mu}{\sigma}\right)-1$$

and so a density of
$$f_n(Y)=\frac{y^{-(n-1)/n}}{n\sigma}\left(\phi\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{y}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\phi\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{y}+\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) \\ =\frac{y^{-(n-1)/n}}{n\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\left(e^{-(\sqrt[n]{y}-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}+ e^{-(\sqrt[n]{y}+\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \right)$$